# toggle button on a report reloads the entire SSRS report in reportviewer - Can i avoid this?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I would like to stop my reportviewer to stop reloading the entire report when i click a toggle button to expand/collapse something inside the report.

Is this possible ?

Can i code something of a extension for it eventually if not supported ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried putting your ReportViewer Control in an IFrame? According to this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090(v=vs.90).aspx Asynchronous works using IFrame and Asynchronous functionality would allow you to reload just the control and not the whole page. 
However, If you are using MVC this is not the case as Asynchronous functionality does not work with it (At least not natively anyways).

Comment: I already use this, but the thing is, I want to collapse/expand inside the report without reloading the entire report, only expand/collapse my table. The entire page doesn't reload already.

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using? Is this running within SharePoint?

Comment: SQL Express 2008, native mode..